# Javascript not being used in 3.8

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm getting an issue on http://bollywoodbang.ca/wp/, it appears that my javascript files aren't working. I called them in `functions.php` using `wp_enqueue_script()`. The inspector says that the right files are getting called, however, the script that's in the files isn't being run. Am I missing something obvious?

The files that aren't working is to recreate [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/) effect for the gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s a problem of order, you are calling new Photostack but the js is not loaded yet. Put the new Photostack just behind photostack.js and see.

Comment: well, your code indicates that. You are puting <script type='text/javascript' src='http://bollywoodbang.ca/wp/wp-content/themes/bollywood/js/photostack.js?ver=1.0'></script> at the bottom of page, but before that is the init: new Photostack( document.getElementById( 'photostack-1' ) The only console error sais exactly that, you are calling the plugin and is not already loaded.

Comment: Sorry rgdesign, you were right! My problem was that one particular js file needed to be called before the others. Thank you!